# Adding field with drop-down list without using database in MVC C#, Microsoft Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dropdownlistview

How can I add a field with drop-down list without using database in MVC C#, Microsoft Entity Framework Core 5?

This is how I declared in the model

```
 [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
```

I want to add like 5 items on the list

How I should write in the "create" view?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-core-5-dropdownlist/.... if this works for you, then try searching the internet before asking the question.